# How can I set text for one specific entry using c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a program for school, that calculates speed or acceleration for students to make it easier to use during lesson. I want to display the solution in an entry. How do I specify which entry it should use. It's a Xamarin Forms project

I tried that piece of code from the Microsoft documentation about Xamarin Forms

```
var MyEntry = new Entry { Text = "I am an Entry" };
```

The problem is, that this code doesn't display anything in my entry

```xml
<StackLayout
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
      Margin="5">
    <Entry Placeholder="V" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="V" />
    <Label Text="=" FontSize="30"/>
    <Entry Placeholder="∆d" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="D" />
    <Label Text="/" FontSize="30"/>
    <Entry Placeholder="∆t" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="T" />
</StackLayout>
```

```cs
var MyEntry = new Entry { Text = "I am an Entry" };
```

It should finally display I am an Entry for example in one of the entries.

Comment: You are instancing a new `Entry` and assigning it to a variable called `MyEntry` but where are you adding that new `Entry` to your UI? Perhaps you are trying to assign "I am Entry" to an existing Entry field in your UI?

Comment: Thank you. But how? How can I specify the var for one of the tree entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your entry a `x:Name`

```
<StackLayout
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
      Margin="5">
    <Entry x:Name="Entry1" Placeholder="V" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="V" />
    <Label Text="=" FontSize="30"/>
    <Entry x:Name="Entry2" Placeholder="∆d" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="D" />
    <Label Text="/" FontSize="30"/>
    <Entry x:Name="Entry3" Placeholder="∆t" HeightRequest="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="T" />
</StackLayout>
```

then in your code-behind

```
Entry1.Text = "One";
Entry2.Text = "Two";
Entry3.Text = "Three";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either give one of your `Entries` in the XAML a `Name`, so that entry is available with that name in your code-behind, and assign the `Text` property to this entry without creating a new one. See [Get Started with XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows#xaml-and-code-interactions) for an example.
Another way would be using a [ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#a-simple-viewmodel).